# Can Django do an UPDATE INNER JOIN, meaning update one model from another based on a matching field, for example ID

Tags: django

Is is possible in Django to do a so called UPDATE INNER JOIN, meaning update one table from another based on a matching field, like ID for example.

To give more context, in PostgreSQL you would achieve this with a query such as:

```
UPDATE users
SET name = R.name,
FROM renamed_users R
WHERE users.id = renamed_users.id;
```

Ref: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update/

Answer (score 2):

Second version of answer after [@ovimunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8065825/ovimunt) comment

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, F

users.objects.filter(
    users__id__in = renamed_users.objects.values('id')
).annotate(
    new_name = Subquery(
        renamed_users.objects.filter(id = OuterRef('id')).values('name')[:1]
    )
).update(name = F('new_name'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work (raising an exception) because F() looks into the model where it is used, not a different model. So in `renamed_users.objects.get(id = F('id'))` the F() looks for `id` in the same `renamed_users` model, not the `users` model. This can also be seen by looking at the actual query that Django makes, i.e. do `from django.db import connection` then, after running the suggested code, doing `connection.queries` gives `[{'sql': 'SELECT "renamed_users"."id", "renamed_users"."name" FROM "renamed_users" WHERE "renamed_users"."id" = "renamed_users"."id" LIMIT 21', 'time': '0.002'}]`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. You should have left the old core in there though so that others who look at this know what doesn't work. Also, my comment is now out of context so it looks wrong since it referred to different code.

Comment: You are welcome. I have tried this solution on my project, it worked. I guess there is no sense to leave wrong answer as the result. Any way it could be found in edit history.